# How to request data from database in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, httprequest

I've built a frontend in my `vue3/laravel8` project and now want to get into the backend. I've been good at learning Vue3 but my knowledge base of Laravel is bare minimum.

I need to fetch an `image link` from a database and render it in a `blade file`.

In Vue3 I would use `axios.get` to send a `request` to a `controller` through an `url` and receive the `image link`. How do I send a `request` to my `controller` in Laravel? Is that even the right way to do it? I thought that maybe Laravel has some `backend tricks` up its sleeve, that Vue does not.

**Edit:**

I know that I can get data like this:

```
$data = DB::select('select * from db_name');
```

Does it have to be sent through an `http response` or can I just import the `variable` in the `blade file`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Are you struggling with sending a request? With sending the proper response?

Comment: Also, in Laravel, you should usually work on your models, and not perform any SQL queries by hand

Comment: I don't know how to get my data from a `database` to a `blade file`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Putting variables into Blade templates should be well documented

Comment: I suggest reading the docs, or following through some tutorials. As already pointed out, getting data into Blade templates is very well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's decompose your question to 2 sub-questions:

1- We need to fetch data when call axios request:

you have to update `routes\api.php` to link the coming request to the proper method located inside your controller

here's an [example](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#basic-controllers)

2- We need to access our data in front-end:

**Vue**

- If you using Vue components you can parse the response data then use it as you prefer

**Laravel Blade System**

- You to call `return view('your-blade-location', payload)`, payload => is your fetched data

here's a [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#view-responses) link